# future value of monthly investments calculator - Python

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am new to python and I am trying to write a program that will calculate the future value of a monthly investment. Here is what I have so far:

```
    #display a welcome message
    print("Welcome to the Future Value Calculator")
    print()

    choice = "y"
    while choice.lower() == "y":
        monthly_invest = int(input("Enter monthly investment:\t"))
        yearly_interest_rate = float(input("Enter yearly interest rate:\t"))
        years = int(input("Enter number of years:\t\t"))

        #convert yearly values to monthly values
        monthly_interest_rate =  yearly_interest_rate / 12 / 100
        months = years * 12
        future_value = 0

        future_value += monthly_invest
        monthly_amount = future_value * monthly_interest_rate
        future_value += monthly_amount

        print()

        #display the result
        for i in range(years):
            print("Year = " + str(i+1) + "\t" + "Future value: " + 
            str(round(future_value)))

        #see if the user wants to continue
        print()
        continue_runs = (input("Continue (y/n)? "))

    print("Bye!")
```

Here is what the outcome is suppose to look like:[image]

I've got the basic layout working good. I am not good at the math part.Can anyone help me with that? Also, can someone tell me how to get "Bye" to print out when the user doesn't want to continue anymore? Right now, it just goes back to the beginning when you hit n.

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is checking the variable `choice` each time it loops. When you get the user input you are setting the answer to `continue_runs` instead of `choice`. You will probably get the right functionally if you set the user input to `choice` instead.

To calculate future value after time series payments you will use the F/A equation.
I found this website with some common formulas: https://www.me.utexas.edu/~me353/lessons/S2_Evaluation/L02_Equivalence/factor_formulas.html

F = A[(1+i)^N - 1]/i

The one you are looking for is "Uniform Series Compound Amount factor". You will use i as the monthly interest rate (annual rate)/12. N is the total number of months. You then multiply this by the A which is the monthly contribution.

Comment: I tried that formula & got an error message showing the code I used: future_value = monthly_invest[(1+monthly_interest_rate)**(months)-1]/monthly_interest_rate
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: I wrote the the equation just for your reference. You have to use parentheses and use the right values for A, i and N.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of while you can break out of a loop using break. I'll leave you to fix the math

```
#display a welcome message
print("Welcome to the Future Value Calculator\n")

monthly_invest = int(input("Enter monthly investment:\t"))
yearly_interest_rate = float(input("Enter yearly interest rate:\t"))
years = int(input("Enter number of years:\t\t"))

#Yearly values to monthly values

monthly_interest_rate =  yearly_interest_rate / 12 / 100
months = years * 12
future_value = 0

for i in range(years):

    future_value += monthly_invest
    monthly_amount = future_value * monthly_interest_rate
    future_value += monthly_amount

    print("\nYear = " + str(i+1) + "\t" + "Future value: " +  str(round(future_value)))

    #Is the loop over?
    if i == years-1:
        break
    #Does the user want to continue?
    continue_runs = (input("\nContinue (y/n)? "))
    if continue_runs.lower()=='n':
        break        

print("Bye!")
```